# Crossover on a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am in the process of creating the crossover function in a genetic algorithm in `Java`.
The 2 "parents" are `2D arrays`:

```
Class[][] p1 = new Class[5][7];
        p1 = parent1;
Class[][] p2 = new Class[5][7];
        p2 = parent2;//parents hold an filled array of Classes of the same dimensions as p1 and p2.
```

and the crossover method returns one "child" that is supposed to hold the first 2 columns of parent 1 and the last 3 of parent 2
How can I select columns from a `2D array` and use them to create the child array?

Answer (score 0):

A multi-dimensional array in java is actually a single dimensional array whose values are instances of an array.  Thus...

```
Class[][] p1 = new Class[5][7];
System.out.println(p1.length);    //5
System.out.println(p1[0].length); //7
System.out.println(p1[1].length); //7
// ...
System.out.println(p1[4].length); //7
```

If I understand your objective, then all you need to do is create a 'results' array (single dimensional) and set the appropriate values at the appropriate indexes.  Here's a start...

```
Class[] results = new Class[5]; //2 + 3 == 5 total
results[0] = p1[0];
//...
```